# Unable to run import scikit-image in jupyter notebook despite successful installation of scikit-image in Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

First, I'm a Windows user. There's a a conflict between Skimage and Tensorflow installs. Each installs ok but they don't run when installed in the same environment. I did 
" pip install scikit-image" and the computer says it's already installed. When I ran import skimage.data in jupyter notebook, I keep getting the error "no module named skimage" although I have scikit-image installed.[image]

Comment: Let me guess. Your code is running in a different environment that you install the skimage in.

Comment: So I installed skimage in Anaconda and I want to run import skimage in jupyter notebook. When I activate scikit-image in anaconda prompt, it says could not find environment scikit-image. So I checked conda environments and scikit-image is not on the list although it's installed.

Comment: From your figures, I can see you have installed the package SKIMAGE in the root environment. So, open the Anaconda Prompt to activate the root environment. 
‘activate root’
Then, do not close this window. Type in it.
‘jupyter notebook’
Try your code in this notebook.

Comment: Done that and still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a Microsoft’s way for you are using Anaconda in windows.

```
Open Anaconda Navigator
```

You can find your installed and Not-installed packages. You can reinstall them. 
[image]

Comment: I checked via Anaconda Navigator that scikit-image is in the root environment. So I use the command 'activate root' in Anaconda prompt and then command 'jupyter notebook' but still not able to import skimage

Comment: It seems impossible.  
Would you like to rebuild another environment with Python 35? The official guidelines of Tensor-Flow run in Python 35, but you are using the root environment of the Anaconda which should be Python 36. When you install Tensor-Flow in Python 35, you may encounter an error of PIP. Also, building a new environment will give you a fresh start.

Comment: This happened to me and I run under macosx.  I do "conda list" and I can see the scikit-image  version and I even re-install using condo-forge but the version same.  One can run the "import skimage" and :from skimage import color" ok under python3 in the command prompt but from the same prompt the juypter notebook does not work. Other like marplotloib under the same notebook all ok.  Just no skimage.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a conda virtual environment, and installing scikit into it, does not mean that it will be available to the ipython kernel in Jupyter notebook. You need to do a few more things to sync everything up.

iPython documentation states

> The Jupyter Notebook and other frontends automatically ensure that the IPython kernel is available. However, if you want to use a kernel with a different version of Python, or in a virtualenv or conda environment, you’ll need to install that manually

Try the following:

## Create and activate a python environment

```
conda create -n py371 python=3.7.1 anaconda
conda activate py371
```

## Install pip and ipykernal

We do this so that we can link the Jupyter Notebook Kernel to the newly created virtual environment "py371"

```
conda install pip
conda install ipykernel # or pip install ipykernel
```

## Link the new virtual environment to ipykernel

We link the newly created virtual environment "py371" to the ipykernel so Jupyter Notebook can see it

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name py371 --display-name "Python (Python 3.7.1)"
```

## Install whatever packages you need, in this case, scikit-image, tensorflow, etc...

conda install -c conda-forge scikit-image

## Launch Jupyter Notebook

```
jupyter notebook
```

## You will now see your new Kernel linked up in Jupyter Notebook

Select the new kernel (Python 3.7.1). Your code will now execute against the selected kernel, which you also linked to your conda virtual environment.

[image: Jupyter Notebook - Virtual Environment - Conda - Kernel Setup]

Further reading and info can be found here: 
[Managing Python](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html)
[Installing the IPython kernel](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html)

Answer (score 0):

I finally brew uninstall miniconda.  Install the whole Anaconda (with the scikit-image built-in) and it worked.  Not that the path I like to take.  But that solve my issue for the moment.